# Wrap enum variants in IntoFuture?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to compile something like the following code. It seems like I need to help it understand that I want all of the match arms to be taken as `futures::future::IntoFuture`, since that's what the outer [`and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.16/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.and_then) is expecting from the callback/closure/delegate.

For now all of the arms are stubbed with the simplest enum variant, `NothingUseful()`, but my goal is ultimately to take various actions depending on the returned HTTP status code and/or body contents when applicable.

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;

use futures::{future, Future, Stream};
use hyper::{Client, Error as HyperError, Response, StatusCode, Uri};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

struct RecurseUrl {
    uri: Uri,
    remaining_attempts: u8,
}

enum FetchResult {
    SimpleData(u16),
    RecurseUrls(Vec<RecurseUrl>),
    NothingUseful(),
}

fn handle_redirect(res: &Response) -> future::FutureResult<FetchResult, HyperError> {
    future::ok(FetchResult::NothingUseful())
}

fn main() {
    let url = "http://someurl.com"
        .parse()
        .expect("Unable to parse URL");

    let mut core = Core::new().expect("Unable to instantiate Tokio Core");
    let client = Client::new(&core.handle());

    let work = client.get(url).and_then(|res| {

        match res.status() {
            StatusCode::TemporaryRedirect => handle_redirect(&res),
            StatusCode::PermanentRedirect => handle_redirect(&res),
            StatusCode::Ok => {
                res.body().concat2().and_then(move |body| {
                    Ok(FetchResult::NothingUseful())
                })
            },
            _ => {
                Ok(FetchResult::NothingUseful())
            }
        }
    });

    core.run(work).expect("Problem running work");
}
```

```
    error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> main.rs:34:13
   |
34 | /             match res.status() {
35 | |                 StatusCode::TemporaryRedirect => handle_redirect(&res),
36 | |                 StatusCode::PermanentRedirect => handle_redirect(&res),
37 | |                 StatusCode::Ok => {
...  |
44 | |                 }
45 | |             }
   | |_____________^ expected struct `futures::FutureResult`, found struct `futures::AndThen`
   |
   = note: expected type `futures::FutureResult<FetchResult, hyper::Error>`
              found type `futures::AndThen<futures::stream::Concat2<hyper::Body>, std::result::Result<FetchResult, hyper::Error>, [closure@main.rs:38:51: 40:22]>`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
  --> main.rs:37:35
   |
37 |                   StatusCode::Ok => {
   |  ___________________________________^
38 | |                     res.body().concat2().and_then(move |body| {
39 | |                         Ok(FetchResult::NothingUseful())
40 | |                     })
41 | |                 },
   | |_________________^
```

Comment: Do you understand that `IntoFuture` is a trait and there's no way to "just" make something into a trait in stable Rust?

Comment: @Shepmaster I understand it's a Trait. I'm hoping I can add some explicit type hints or casting or something. It's easy enough to have each of the arms return an actual future using e.g., future::ok() but then I run into problems where some of the resulting impls are AndThen and some are FutureResult and when I try to assign them to a variable typed with a Trait they should all have in common, it complains about not being marked for Sized. Maybe I should be taking some completely different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want all of the match arms to be taken as `futures::future::IntoFuture`, since that's what the outer `and_then` is expecting from the callback/closure/delegate.

`and_then` expects that the return type of the closure to be a **single concrete type** that *implements the trait* `IntoFuture`. Your `match` returns multiple concrete types — this is not allowed in Rust as the compiler wouldn't know how much stack space to allocate.

You need to convert all the various types into a single unified type. The *easiest* is to box them all, creating a trait object (`Box<Future<Item = FetchResult, Error = hyper::Error>>`):

```
let work = client.get(url).and_then(|res| -> Box<Future<Item = FetchResult, Error = hyper::Error>> {
        match res.status() {
            StatusCode::TemporaryRedirect => Box::new(handle_redirect(&res)),
            StatusCode::PermanentRedirect => Box::new(handle_redirect(&res)),
            StatusCode::Ok => Box::new(
                res.body()
                    .concat2()
                    .map(move |body| FetchResult::NothingUseful()),
            ),
            _ => Box::new(future::ok(FetchResult::NothingUseful())),
        }
    },
);
```

You could also create your own type and implement `Future` for that. This allows you to avoid any allocation:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;

use futures::{Async, Future, Poll};
use hyper::client::{FutureResponse, HttpConnector};
use hyper::{Client, Response, StatusCode, Uri};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

struct RecurseUrl {
    client: Client<HttpConnector>,
    future: FutureResponse,
    remaining_attempts: u8,
}

impl RecurseUrl {
    fn new(client: Client<HttpConnector>, uri: Uri) -> Self {
        let future = client.get(uri);
        Self {
            client,
            future,
            remaining_attempts: 3,
        }
    }
}

impl Future for RecurseUrl {
    type Item = hyper::Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Self::Item, Self::Error> {
        let response = try_ready!(self.future.poll());

        match response.status() {
            StatusCode::TemporaryRedirect | StatusCode::PermanentRedirect => {
                if self.remaining_attempts == 0 {
                    panic!("return a real error")
                }

                let next_uri = get_redirect_uri_from_response(&response);
                let next_future = self.client.get(next_uri);
                self.future = next_future;
                self.remaining_attempts -= 1;

                Ok(Async::NotReady)
            }
            StatusCode::Ok => Ok(Async::Ready(response)),
            _ => panic!("return a real error"),
        }
    }
}

fn get_redirect_uri_from_response(_response: &Response) -> Uri {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {
    let uri = "http://someurl.com".parse().expect("Unable to parse URL");

    let mut core = Core::new().expect("Unable to instantiate Tokio Core");
    let client = Client::new(&core.handle());

    let work = RecurseUrl::new(client, uri);
    core.run(work).expect("Problem running work");
}
```

You could then handle reading URIs out of the bodies of the responses with something like this:

```
use futures::stream::{Stream, FuturesUnordered, Concat2};

struct WebCrawler {
    client: Client<HttpConnector>,
    to_fetch: FuturesUnordered<FutureResponse>,
    fetching: FuturesUnordered<Concat2<hyper::Body>>,
}

impl WebCrawler {
    fn new(client: Client<HttpConnector>, uri: Uri) -> Self {
        let future = client.get(uri);
        let to_fetch: FuturesUnordered<_> = Some(future).into_iter().collect();

        Self {
            client,
            to_fetch,
            fetching: FuturesUnordered::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl Stream for WebCrawler {
    type Item = hyper::Chunk;
    type Error = hyper::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        loop {
            match self.to_fetch.poll()? {
                Async::Ready(Some(s)) => {
                    self.fetching.push(s.body().concat2())
                },
                Async::Ready(None) | Async::NotReady => break,
            }
        }

        loop {
            match self.fetching.poll()? {
                Async::Ready(Some(body)) => {
                    for uri in get_uris_from_body(&body) {
                        self.to_fetch.push(self.client.get(uri));
                    }
                    return Ok(Async::Ready(Some(body)));
                },
                Async::Ready(None) | Async::NotReady => break,
            }
        }

        if self.to_fetch.is_empty() && self.fetching.is_empty() {
            Ok(Async::Ready(None))
        } else {
            Ok(Async::NotReady)
        }
    }
}

fn get_uris_from_body(_body: &hyper::Chunk) -> Vec<Uri> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

This implementation was cribbed from that of [`BufferUnordered`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/blob/0.1.17/src/stream/buffer_unordered.rs). You'd need to enhance it to pass the depth of the crawl around and manage it, but I think this is a good sketch of what is possible.

Comment: Could you add some clarification around creating an "enum for each variant and ... implementing Future ... by delegating to each inner implementation"?

Comment: @steamer25 I played a bit with the enum but didn't really like it so I put up an alternative. I see your original had `RecurseUrls(Vec<RecurseUrl>)` — is it possible to take a single URI and then need to search *multiple* from that?

Comment: Haven't looked through the updated answer yet (big thanks!) but yeah, my thought is to handle redirects and links to subsequent pages using the same logic. I.e., the HTTP response might send a redirect for the requested page or it might send HTML with a bunch of hrefs for new pages to chase. The depth of recursion should be limited in either case.

Comment: Thanks again. The Future implementation example gives me a better understanding of the framework. I'll probably end up with some sort of queuing for the recursion, potentially allowing them to be processed in other threads/event-loops.

Comment: @steamer25 not for the pure *recursion* of the redirects — that's already handled by this future implementation. If you mean for continuing to crawl the outgoing links, then yes, a queue would make sense. I have an idea in the back of my head that I'll work on sometime later today.